# How can I pass more than one query to a search field using Capybara?

Tags: ruby, capybara

I have a few different search terms that I want to pass to a search input field using Capybara. I'm stuck on how to pass the array to the input field.

I have assigned the terms to an array and tried to pass it as follows:

```
search_terms = ['term1', 'term2', 'term3']

search_terms.each do |term|
  page.find(:css, 'input[id="LookupField"]').set("#{term}")
  ...
end
```

That didn't work.

How can I pass the search terms to the input field?

Comment: would it not be better to split the searching for each term into its own scenario?

Comment: That would entail repeating the code for each term.

Comment: true but it would allow you test each search term in isolation.

Comment: Right, and I initially did it that way, but I'm looking to DRY the code.

Comment: What exactly is not working? and what are you expecting the result to be? As an aside if you're really working on cleaning up your code it could be written as  `page.fill_in('LookupField', with: term)`

Comment: @TomWalpole - Hi again. I am trying to search each term then push the results to an array. What happens is the 1st term searches fine, but then when the 2nd term is searched, the results of the 1st term's search are lost. I would love to be able to persist the results of all three, then push to my array. Oh, and page.fill_in kept returning a no method error which is why I'm not using it.

Comment: @NeyLive Assuming the page replaces the previous results with new results you will need to save the results to your array after each search, then input the new term, and then somehow determine when the new results have shown up (that is dependent on how the page works - is it ajax, does it open a new page with the search term in the url, etc) and repeat.  Add more of your code if you need help with that, and explain how the search works.  `fill_in` is implemented as find(...).set(...)  so if the second works `fill_in` should too - what error exactly were you getting

Comment: A new page loads with the search term in the url. I suppose I'll just have to repeat the process for each search term. I only have 3 for now, so it's no big deal, but whoever tries to add more search terms later might get a bit of a headache. Regarding page.fill_in, I was getting an error that stated `undefined method 'fill_in'` so I gave up using fill_in when find(...).set(...) worked.